# How to format a date value on Symfony?

Tags: symfony

Im fetching data from a facebook user object, the birthday field have this format: **MM/DD/YYYY**. In Symfony2 using doctrine I define my Birthday field like:

```
/**
 * @var \Date $birthday
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="birthday", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $birthday;
```

This on the database generates the format **YYYY-DD-MM**, Im trying to format the facebook format into something that I can use with symfony but with no success, this is my attempt:

```
if(isset($fbuser["birthday"]))  {                   //CHECK FOR FIELD birthday
   $date_pz = explode('/',$fbuser["birthday"]);
   // Firts try: $norm_date = array('year' => $date_pz[2], 'month' => $date_pz[0], 'day' => $date_pz[1]);
   // Second try: $norm_date = $date_pz[2] .'-'. $date_pz[0] .'-'. $date_pz[1]);
   $userinfo->setBirthday($norm_date); }
```

And Im always getting:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/vhosts/punctis.com/httpdocs/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateType.php
>   on line 44

That means that im not sending the string in the format Symfony expect, so the questions here is, how to format that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Doctrine-Type `Date` is expecting a a `DateTime`-object. You could use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to create said object.

Either you do it in your entity (e.g. in `setBirthday($birthday)`) or create a custom DateType which does the formatting for you.

Comment: can you please be more specific about the first solution DateTime::createFromFormat()  ? How can I use it on my code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php In your case something like: `$this->birthday = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $fbuser["birthday"]);`

Answer (score 4):

If you have a var output like this:

```
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($yourDateTimeObjectVar);die;

//outputs;
DateTime Object
(
  [date] => 2013-12-16 15:17:27
  [timezone_type] => 3
  [timezone] => America/New_York
)
```

Then, you just have to do:

```
echo $yourDateTimeObjectVar->format('d/m/Y');
```

which will output:

16/12/2013

PS:
In this case, the object came from MySql datetime column and it was insert like this:

```
$myOrder = new OrderStatus();
$myOrder->setDateOrder(\new DateTime());
$em->persist($myOrder);
$em->flush()
```

Var ORM Declaration:

```
 @ORM\Column(name="DateOrder", type="datetime", nullable=true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass a string to **$userinfo->setBirthday($norm_date)** but a **DateTime object**, try

```
 $userinfo->setBirthday(new \DateTime($norm_date));
 $userinfo->setBirthday(new \DateTime('now'));
 $userinfo->setBirthday(new \DateTime('2013-01-15'));
 $userinfo->setBirthday(new \DateTime('+2 days'), new \DateTimeZone('UCT'));
```

You can construct a **DateTime** object in a number of ways, check the docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php